# Several connection to remote internet website

Tags: .net, http, httpwebrequest

As part of an experiment, I am trying to have 32 concurrent connection connect to a website on the internet and download the html page associated to each url of the connection but I am getting the following exception on about 10 to 20 of those connections

```
 System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: 
    An existing    connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. --->
    System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly 
    closed by the remote host at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, 
    Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
```

Answer (score 2):

1. the server can limit you to X connections
2. because you can only have true concurrency up to the number of cores in your cpu, after that it's random what connection is executed first
3. can be any step you listed
4. the server wants to be accessable by as many unique persons (IP adresses) as possible
5. different IP adresses, which needs another physical connection or piping some connections through a proxy server, if neither is possible you can't get around it

Comment: No, I don't. Also, I wouldn't give it out for such a purpose, as those limits are there for a reason and people such oblige to them.